# Ruby create an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I've got a variable I'd like to use as a key to a hash that contains its own key and array.

e.g.

```
custArray = Array.new
custArray << {"c1001" => {"purchases" => ["prod01"]}}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
if custArray[:c1001].exists?
  custArray[{:c1001["purchases"]} << "prod02"]
end
```

but I'm just totally stuck.

Comment: Prefer `cust_array` over `custArray` in Ruby.
Also, "c1001" and :c1001 are not equivalent hash keys.

Comment: I suggest that in future you not be in such a rush to select an answer. There's no hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve it with:

```
if c = custArray.find { |h| h.key? 'c1001' }
  c.dig('c1001', 'purchases') << "prod2"
end
```

Or if you can have more than one result with this key:

```
custArray.select { |h| h.key? 'c1001' }.each do |c|
  c.dig('c1001', 'purchases') << "prod2"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use select from the array of hashes to see if the key is there:

```
target = custArray.find { |h| h.key? 'c1001' }
target['c1001']['purchases'] <<  "prod02" unless target.nil?
```

Or if array contains multiple hashes with the same key:

```
custArray.select { |h| h.key? 'c1001' }.each do |h|
  h['c1001']['purchases'] <<  "prod02" 
end
```

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question.  That absolutely worked.

Comment: I edited my answer as the first answer I gave was incorrect

Comment: See last update. But also be aware, an array may contain multiple hashes that have the same keys.  So make sure however you're building your array, those keys are unique. Also prefer snake case in ruby `cust_array` vs `custArray`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update the first instance of the array you can do:

```
target = custArray.find { |hash| hash.key? 'c1001' }
target['c1001']['purchases'] << 'prod02' if target
```

If you want to update all instances of the array you can do (backslashes are for console purposes only):

```
custArray \
  .select { |hash| hash.key? 'c1001' } \
  .each { |hash| hash['c1001']['purchases'] << 'prod02' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can write something similar to code that you already provide

```
custArray.each do |h|
  h['c1001']['purchases'] << 'prod02' if h.keys.include?('c1001')
end
```

That allows reducing the count of iteration loops

Comment: This solution will also handle if you have duplicate array values with the same hash key `c1001`

Answer (score 0):

```
custArray.find { |h| h.key?('c1001') }&.dig('c1001', 'purchases')&.push("prod02")
  #=> ["prod01", "prod02"]
custArray
  #=> [{"c1001"=>{"purchases"=>["prod01", "prod02"]}}]

custArray.find { |h| h.key?('c1002') }&.dig('c1002', 'purchases')&.push("prod02")
  #=> nil
custArray
  #=> [{"c1001"=>{"purchases"=>["prod01"]}}]

custArray.find { |h| h.key?('c1001') }&.dig('c1001', 'popsicles')&.push("prod02")
  #=> nil
custArray
  #=> [{"c1001"=>{"purchases"=>["prod01"]}}]
```

`&` is Ruby's [Safe Navigation Operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). See also [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig). Both made their debut in Ruby v2.3.